# jQuery animate div and select option

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-animate

I have some experince in making "sliders" with jQuery, but for the first time I have this problem. In my div I inserted a select field and when I'm trying to change it, after the div slides out, it makes it slide back.

I posted the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kingston/fpjDg/).

Comment: What is it you want to happen exactly? It seems to work fine here (safari). In which browser is it you are experiencing problems?

Comment: I do not want to hide div after selecting option from the select box

Comment: You're getting that in IE maybe? Safari and firefox work fine here.

Comment: In IE and Firefox. I sent it to my few friend and they get the same problem.

Comment: It looks like the option area in select box is outside the main div, so it hides. I have no idea for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".slider").hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).animate({
            left: "0"
        }, 700)
    }, function(e) {
        var within = $(e.target).parents().is('.slider')
        if (!within) {
            jQuery(".slider").stop(true, false).animate({
                left: "-270px"
            }, 700);
        }
    });
});
```

***[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/fpjDg/14/)***

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem did not disappear.

Comment: When i want to choose options in select box, the div still hides. And that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this code should do your job..!! ,

Working Demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/fpjDg/13/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".slider").hover(function(e) {

        jQuery(this).animate({
            left: "0"
        }, 700)
    }, function() {

        //  e.preventDefault();
        //slide out when options are selected.
        $("select").change(function() {

            //Call this  line only when the work is completed in the  form.
            jQuery(".slider").stop(true, false).animate({
                left: "-270px"
            }, 700);

        }); //change
    }); //hover
}); //ready
```

Comment: It seems ok, but after the mouse is outside the div, it doesn't hide. Tested in IE and FF.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be expected behaviour, I see a few options.

1) Use a [jQuery plugin](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins) to swap the select element for a dropdown that uses div/ul/li elements. This should not trigger the mouseleave event as it sees these elements as part of the box. (For some reason this doesn't happen with select box options)

2) This is more hacky maybe but you could check on mouseleave if the mouse coordinates are inside the box or not, if so `don't hide the box`, else `hide the box`.

3) Instead of hiding on mouseleave, use a close button, or a click handler on the document or the like.